# Laravel - How to compare two time fields?

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-8

[image: Database table]

Hello There!
I want to get **only the rows where the punch_in_time is greater than the expected_punch_in_time** (You can see the columns in the picture link above).
I searched a lot and I did not found anything helpful, I tried the "whereDate" method but it turns out that it only works on datetime fields and not only time as in my case.
Any help would be appreciated!
Thank you.

Comment: If you actually are using the `TIME` data type, I would expect this to work: `WHERE punch_in_time > expected_punch_in_time`, but even if you use `VARCHAR`, or `TEXT`, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use whereTime function in querybuilder

```
whereTime('punch_in_time', '>', 'expected_punch_in_time')
```

for more details refer link https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries

Answer (score 0):

Use eloquent: `whereTime (colum, '>' colum)`;

Or if want pure SQL u can use this:

```
SELECT * FROM testTime WHERE
CAST(punch_in_time AS TIME) > CAST(expected_punch_in_time AS TIME);

SELECT * FROM testTime WHERE
punch_in_time > expected_punch_in_time;
```

fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/unRTudcJHfanEDK5VnP95x/0)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I figured it out, I have used the "whereColumn" method and it worked well.

```
public function ScopeLateDrivers($query)
{
    return $query->whereColumn('punch_in_time', '>', 'expected_punch_in_time');
}
```